# Vercel + express DELETE cors issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, vercel

I am building an API with vercel and expressJs.

I have `GET` and `POST` endpoint working properly, and for some reason, the `DELETE` endpoint that I have send teh following error in my javascript console from the client (angular, using angular HttpClient for all requests):

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/clients/27' from origin 'http://localhost:1420' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

I tried using the `cors()` middleware, but it didn't change anything.

I then found [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13148080) on an other post that fix my issue if I start my api as `node index.js` but the second I go `vercel dev` the `DELETE` endpoint raise this cors issue again.

I've tried playing around with my `vercel.json` headers section under routs but it seems like nothing changes.

here is my current `vercel.json` file:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "buildCommand": "npx prisma generate && npx prisma db push",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "index.js",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between allowing methods at the route level and allowing methods for CORS. AFAIU, you've only done the former, not the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the issue is in deployment only right? So try to look up subdomains. It means putting your API inside your front end so they share the same access I'd say. For the delete route or method make sure the URL and ports are good I don't know if you're using an env file check that too.

Comment: it was also happening in dev using vercel dev. I chose to go with epressjs directly and deploy my api to a VPS behind an NGINX proxy